# TFDV Tensorflow Data Validation: how can I save/load the protobuf schema to/from a file

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, tensorflow-data-validation

TFDV generates schema as a Schema protocol buffer. However it seems that there is no helper function to write/read schema to/from a file.

```
schema = tfdv.infer_schema(stats)
```

How can I save it/load it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following methods to write/load the schema to/from a file.

```
from google.protobuf import text_format
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io
from tensorflow_metadata.proto.v0 import schema_pb2

def write_schema(schema, output_path):
  schema_text = text_format.MessageToString(schema)
  file_io.write_string_to_file(output_path, schema_text)

def load_schema(input_path):
  schema = schema_pb2.Schema()
  schema_text = file_io.read_file_to_string(input_path)
  text_format.Parse(schema_text, schema)
  return schema
```

Comment: Wow. Nice! I searched quite much and couldn’t find this, very helpful!

Comment: Hi Paul Suganthan, quick question, is there a way to merge protobuf with same format, like stat files? We are processing multiple files everyday and would like to run the skew/drift comparator between today and yesterday files, but comparing one to one doesn't make sense, but merging all files to one big CSV would be too intensive on RAM to compute stats, so I think about merging stats in only one stats protobuf

Comment: Hi Vincent. Currently it is not possible to merge the stats files. One way to achieve your goal is to compute stats over all the yesterday's CSV files. To do that you don't need to merge all the CSV files. You can already generate statistics over multiple CSV files by specifying a file pattern for the data_location argument in generate_statistics_from_csv method. The pattern can contain glob characters (*, ?, and [...] sets). Thanks for the feedback on this. We would consider adding support for merging stats files.

Comment: oh nice, didn't check if that was possible. Thanks for explaining! Got ton of feedback if you need, currently implementing it on a big production ETL :) 
I am the one who placed the issue on githud regarding python snappy, you can contact me on githud if you want :) Thanks

Comment: Hi Vincent. Would like to hear about your feedback. Can you create an issue in GitHub and share your feedback there?

Answer (score 2):

If you will be using it with **Tensorflow Transform** then I would suggest the following functions:

```
import tensorflow_data_validation as tfdv
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io
from tensorflow_transform.tf_metadata import metadata_io

# Define file path
file_io.recursive_create_dir(OUTPUT_DIR)
schema_file = os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, 'schema.pbtxt')

# Write schema
tfdv.write_schema_text(schema, schema_file)

# Read schema with tfdv
schema = tfdv.load_schema_text(schema_file)

# Read schema with tensorflow_transform
schema = metadata_io.read_metadata(OUTPUT_DIR)
```

The output is human-readable - similar to JSON. But if you prefer to save it in plain **JSON format** then you can use the following:

```
from google.protobuf import json_format
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io
from tensorflow_metadata.proto.v0 import schema_pb2

def write_schema(schema, output_path):
    schema_text = json_format.MessageToJson(schema)
    file_io.write_string_to_file(output_path, schema_text)

def load_schema(input_path):
    schema_text = file_io.read_file_to_string(input_path)
    schema = json_format.Parse(schema_text, schema_pb2.Schema())
    return schema
```

Or if you don't need it to be in human-readable format you can use SerializeToString() and ParseFromString(data) for de/serialization like described [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial#parsing-and-serialization).

Answer (score 1):

tensorflow_data_validation itself provides you util functions for this:

```
from tensorflow_data_validation.utils.schema_util import write_schema_text, load_schema_text
write_schema_text(schema, "./my_schema")
schema = load_schema_text("./my_schema")
```

Comment: Yes, that has been added after the dev replied to this question on their git